# Why can't I pass a sentence value to a jQuery function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to run a function like this:

`onclick="preConfirm(New Lots Avenue,40.660223,-73.896668);"`

But I always get an error in the console saying

`Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Step 1: Don't use inline event handlers/JavaScript

Comment: String values need to be enclosed in quotes.  In, like, every programming language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
onclick="preConfirm('New Lots Avenue','40.660223','-73.896668');"
```

Answer (score 1):

Farhad's answer is correct, but you might also take j08691's comment into consideration and separate your JS from your HTML:

1) Use data attributes to hold your information

```
<button
  data-address="New Lots Avenue"
  data-lat="40.660223"
  data-lng="-73.896668"
>Confirm</button>
```

2) And use JavaScript to grab that information in the `preConfirm` function:

```
// Grab the button and add an event listener
const button = document.querySelector('button');
button.addEventListener('click', preConfirm, false);

function preConfirm(e) {

  // dataset is an object containing your information
  // { address → "New Lots Avenue", lat → "40.660223", lng → "-73.896668" }
  console.log(e.target.dataset);
}
```

Or, more simply with jQuery:

```
$('button').click(preConfirm);

function preConfirm() {
  console.log($(this).data());
}
```

You can access the dataset object as normal:

```
dataset.address // New Lots Avenue
dataset.lat // 40.660223
dataset.lng // -73.896668
```

**[Vanilla JS DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/32s4tpgb/1/)** | **[jQuery DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/n8f11qpf/3/)**